# html support in android default email client

Tags: android

Does Android Default Email Client supports the html content?
Any ideas ?
        i am using like this.

```
int_email.setType("*/*");
int_email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(message)) ;
```

Comment: use JavaMailAPI to send email in html format http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124

Answer (score 0):

You can set type to `plain/text` and passe your message directly

```
int_email.setType("plain/text");
int_email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message) ;
```